# Form doesn't always pass data to TravelClick

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form (booking engine) that collects information from customers to find rooms to rent for their vacation. It transfers the data to the TravelClick (TC) system. Something in TC's system changed at some point, and now the booking engine doesn't always pass the data. About 1/10 times the data will submit properly to TC and the page will display available room information. If you refresh the page or close out and go back in, pick the same dates, it will not pass along the form data and the TC page will show a default page where you select your dates. TC refuses to look at the code we have to try to see what the problem is, and they refuse to troubleshoot the code in the documentation they sent. There are no errors that appear either. I'm at a loss trying to get this to work. 
Here is the HTML code for the form (built in RSForm for Joomla):

```
<form method="post" id="userForm" name="resform" onsubmit="return false;" action="https://bookings.ihotelier.com/Vista-Cay-Resort-by-Millenium/bookings.jsp">
<!-- Do not remove this ID, it is used to identify the page so that the pagination script can work correctly -->
<fieldset class="uk-form uk-form-horizontal formContainer" id="rsform_8_page_0">
<div class="uk-form-row rsform-block rsform-block-datein">
        <label class="uk-form-label control-label formControlLabel" data-uk-tooltip="{pos:'top-left'}" title="" for="DateIn">Check-In:<br><span style="font-size: 75%;">(mm/dd/yyyy)</span></label>
        <div class="uk-form-controls formControls">
            <input id="txtcal8_0" name="form[DateIn]" type="text" value="" class="rsform-calendar-box rsform-calendar-box"><input id="btn8_0" type="button" value="View Calendar" class="rsform-calendar-box btnCal rsform-calendar-button uk-button uk-button-default" onclick="RSFormPro.YUICalendar.showHideCalendar('cal8_0Container');"><div id="cal8_0Container" style="clear:both;display:none;position:absolute;z-index:9997"></div>
<input id="hiddencal8_0" type="hidden" name="hidden[8_DateIn]"><span class="formValidation"><span id="component61" class="formNoError">Invalid Input</span></span>              
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row rsform-block rsform-block-dateout">
        <label class="uk-form-label control-label formControlLabel" data-uk-tooltip="{pos:'top-left'}" title="" for="DateOut">Check-Out:<br><span style="font-size: 75%;">(mm/dd/yyyy)</span></label>
        <div class="uk-form-controls formControls">
            <input id="txtcal8_1" name="form[DateOut]" type="text" value="" class="rsform-calendar-box rsform-calendar-box"><input id="btn8_1" type="button" value=" View Calendar" class="rsform-calendar-box btnCal rsform-calendar-button uk-button uk-button-default" onclick="RSFormPro.YUICalendar.showHideCalendar('cal8_1Container');"><div id="cal8_1Container" style="clear:both;display:none;position:absolute;z-index:9996"></div>
<input id="hiddencal8_1" type="hidden" name="hidden[8_DateOut]"><span class="formValidation"><span id="component62" class="formNoError">Invalid Input</span></span>             
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row rsform-block rsform-block-adults">
        <label class="uk-form-label control-label formControlLabel" data-uk-tooltip="{pos:'top-left'}" title="" for="Adults">Adults:</label>
        <div class="uk-form-controls formControls">
            <select name="form[Adults][]" id="Adults" class="rsform-select-box"><option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option></select><span class="formValidation"><span id="component64" class="formNoError">Invalid Input</span></span>                
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row rsform-block rsform-block-children">
        <label class="uk-form-label control-label formControlLabel" data-uk-tooltip="{pos:'top-left'}" title="" for="Children">Children:</label>
        <div class="uk-form-controls formControls">
            <select name="form[Children][]" id="Children" class="rsform-select-box"><option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option></select><span class="formValidation"><span id="component65" class="formNoError">Invalid Input</span></span>                
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-form-row rsform-block rsform-block-submit">
        <label class="uk-form-label control-label formControlLabel" data-uk-tooltip="{pos:'top-left'}" title="" for="Submit"></label>
        <div class="uk-form-controls formControls">
            <input type="submit" name="form[Submit]" id="Submit" onclick="postIHForm (document.resform)" class="button button-2 button-xsmall" value="Book Now"><span class="formValidation"></span>                
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="form[HotelID]" id="HotelID" value="14939"><input type="hidden" name="form[Length]" id="Length" value="">
</fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="form[formId]" value="8">
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript code sending the form data to TC:

```
<script>
function postIHForm(oForm){
    var qs = "";

    qs = qs + "?hotelid=" + document.getElementById("HotelID").value;
    if (oForm.LanguageID) { qs = qs + "&languageid=" + oForm.LanguageID.value}
    qs = qs + "&datein=" + document.getElementById("txtcal8_0").value;
    if (document.getElementById("Length")) { qs = qs + "&length=" + document.getElementById("Length").value }
    if (document.getElementById("txtcal5_1")) { qs = qs + "&dateout=" + document.getElementById("txtcal8_1").value }
    qs = qs + "&Adults=" + document.getElementById("Adults").value;
    if (document.getElementById("Children")) { qs = qs + "&children=" + document.getElementById("Children").value }
        var target = 'https://booking.ihotelier.com/istay/istay.jsp' + qs;
        var be_link = "";
        ga(function(tracker) {
            var linker = new window.gaplugins.Linker(tracker);
            be_link = linker.decorate(target);
        });
         window.open(be_link);
}
</script>
```

Action: https://bookings.ihotelier.com/Vista-Cay-Resort-by-Millenium/bookings.jsp

Additional HTML attributes: onsubmit="return false;"

Do you see anything incorrect or anything as to why the form wouldn't always pass the data to TC?

Comment: Is something timing out?

Comment: Not that I can tell. It all happens within a second or two

Answer (score 0):

My post URL to iHotelier during a recently upgrade to their 4.0 platform changed to https://reservations.travelclick.com/XXXXX

Where XXXXX is the HotelID. Also, in the documentation all the parameters are pascal case - DateIn, DateOut, Length, Adults, Children.

Example: https://reservations.travelclick.com/14939?Adults=2&Children=0